# sparkMLlib MinHashLSH Must have at least 1 non zero entry exeception?

Tags: apache-spark-mllib

I want to find the repeated article with MinHash model provided by Spark MLlib, then I encountered an exception: "Must have at least 1 non zero entry.".

I belive it is triggered by 
`val featurizedData = mh.transform(tmp).cache()` .
But I cann't really understand what is go wrong .
code:

```
 val data = spark.read.format("jdbc").
  option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test").
  option("dbtable", "article").
  option("user", "root").
  option("password", "123456").load().
  select("id", "content").
  map(r =>
    (r.getString(0), segment(r.getString(1))
  ).toDF("id", "content").where("content is not null").cache()
val cvModel: CountVectorizerModel = new CountVectorizer().
  setInputCol("content").
  setOutputCol("features").
  setMinDF(2).
  fit(data)
val tmp = cvModel.transform(data).cache()
val mh = new MinHashLSH().
  setNumHashTables(5).
  setInputCol("features").
  setOutputCol("hashes").
  fit(tmp)
val featurizedData = mh.transform(tmp).cache()
val res = mh.approxSimilarityJoin(featurizedData, featurizedData, 0.1, "sim").
  select(col("datasetA.id").alias("idA"),
    col("datasetB.id").alias("idB"),
    col("sim"))
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
res.toDF().write.format("jdbc").
  mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).
  option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test). 
  option("dbtable", "article_duplicated_913").
  option("user", "root").
  option("password", "123456").
  save()
```

exception info:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (vector) => array<vector>)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply2_1$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:216)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1038)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1029)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:969)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1029)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:760)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)                          


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Must have at least 1 non zero entry.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.MinHashLSHModel$$anonfun$1.apply(MinHashLSH.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.MinHashLSHModel$$anonfun$1.apply(MinHashLSH.scala:56)
    ... 36 more .
```

[referenced code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/MinHashLSH.scala#L64)

Comment: Running into the same issue but I can't figure out what's wrong. I am dropping all the sparse vectors returned by CountVectorizer that have 0 non-zero elements but I am still getting the same error. Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

check your vector，make sure all of that not like (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

Answer (score 0):

It should be related with nulls or malformed data in the input. I would suggest adding a filter that checks that you have at least one element in each row of `content` before making the lsh, e.g. something like

`.filter(size($"content")>=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Even with filtering out all the sparse vectors that have no elements via:

```
.filter(~F.col('Vectorized').cast(T.StringType()).contains('[]'))
```

The error still remains.